# How to do client side updates in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I'd like to do client side component updates. Example: disable a button when a checkbox is clicked:

```
<h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true" onchange="button.disabled=true" />
<h:commandButton id="button" value="Save" />
```

The above doesn't work. Is there a way to do this declaratively in JSF?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because the JSF component ID is not necessarily the same as the generated HTML ID. JSF composes the HTML element ID and form element name based on the ID's of all [`UINamingContainer`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UINamingContainer.html) components in the tree -if any. The `UIForm` component is one of them. Rightclick the page in webbrowser and choose *View Source*. See and learn.

There are two ways to solve this problem:

1. Set `prependId` attribtue of `<h:form>` to `false`.

   ```
   <h:form prependId="false">
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true" onclick="button.disabled=true" />
       <h:commandButton id="button" value="Save" />
   </h:form>
   ```

   Note that I'd rather use `onclick="button.disabled=!checked"` instead. The `onchange` is only fired when the input element loses focus and that is non-intuitive in case of checkboxes and radiobuttons. Also, you'd like to turn it back on when the checkbox is checked again, right?
2. Give the `<h:form>` a fixed ID so that you know how the generated form element name look like:

   ```
   <h:form id="form">
       <h:selectBooleanCheckbox value="true" onclick="form['form:button'].disabled=true" />
       <h:commandButton id="button" value="Save" />
   </h:form>
   ```

   The brace notation is mandatory because the `:` is an illegal identifier character and just `onclick="form:button.disabled=true"` won't work. Also here, I'd rather use `onclick="form['form:button'].disabled=!checked` instead.

The same problem applies on `document.getElementById()` as well. So simply replacing `button` by `document.getElementById('button')` alone won't fix the problem.

Comment: +1 I remember that I had a hard time understanding this when I started with JSF, and I think this is the way to go if you want to keep your code clean.

Comment: What if I want to change an attribute of a component that does not exist in the rendered HTML output. I guess the component writer needs to expose a client side JS API, right?

Comment: Use `<f:ajax>` to do partial updates which get reflected in both server and client sides.

Answer (score 2):

simply use javascript

```
document.getElementById("buttonId").disabled="true";
```

[Check this](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_button_disabled)

Comment: Can you give an example? Is there a way to do this declaratively in JSF (I've updated the question).

Comment: @Theo Ultimately JSF will be  HTML at browser,  just use the updated code